# How to pass a class as a parameter to a method as if it were a dynamic variable?

Tags: java, class, methods, reflection, mediastore

I'm trying to pass classes depending on some conditions of where a method is being called. If a method is called in Albums, use class "album", but if is called in Artists use class "artist".

I'm still new in Java, can't seem to get hold of this.

Here's the method that's suppose to call these different classes.

```
private int songCounter;
    public ArrayList getSongs(Context context, String type, int max, Class cls){

        String select;

        switch (type) {
            case "albums": {
                select = IS_MUSIC + " != 0 AND ALBUM NOT NULL) GROUP BY (ALBUM";
                break;
            }
            case "artists": {
                 select = IS_MUSIC + " != 0 AND ARTIST NOT NULL) GROUP BY (ARTIST";
                break;
            }
            default: {
                 select = IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
                break;
            }
        }

        ArrayList songList          = new ArrayList();

        Cursor c                    = context.getContentResolver().query(EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null,select,null,null);
        if(c!= null && c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                long    id          = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(_ID));
                long    albumId     = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(ALBUM_ID));
                String  artist      = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ARTIST));
                String  album       = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ALBUM));
                String  title       = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TITLE));

                songCounter++;

                if (songCounter < max) {
/////// I'm having a problem here, how do I call "cls"?
                        songList.add(new cls(id, album, artist, title, getArt(context, albumId)));
                }
            }
            while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
        return songList;
    }
```

**Below is a class "Album", an example of the kind of classes that needs to be called.**

```
public class Album {
    private long    id;
    private String  title;
    private String  artist;
    private String  album;
    private String  year;
    private String  genre;
    private String  duration;
    private BitmapDrawable art;

    public Album(long songID, String songTitle, String songArtist, String songAlbum, BitmapDrawable songArt) {
        id          = songID;
        title       = songTitle;
        artist      = songArtist;
        album       = songAlbum;
        art     = songArt;
    }

    public long getID(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public String getArtist(){
        return artist;
    }

    public String getAlbum(){
        return album;
    }

    public String getDuration(){
        return duration;
    }

    public BitmapDrawable getArt(){
        return art;
    }

}
```

**And how I'm trying to call the "getSongs" method.**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);

        View rootView       = inflater.inflate(R.layout.library_albums, container, false);
        this.mView          = rootView;
        songView            = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.album_list);
        songList            = new ArrayList<Album>();
        this.music          = new Music();

This is where I don't know what to do also/////

        songList            = music.getSongs(mView.getContext(), "albums", 200, "album/artist/song class here);

        AlbumAdapter songAdt = new AlbumAdapter(mView.getContext(), songList);
        songView.setAdapter(songAdt);
        return rootView;
    }
```

Maybe I just need a new kind of architecture for this?

Comment: Which version of java you are using?

Comment: @kakurala version 7.

Comment: What's in IS_MUSIC ? also, why do you want to pass the class ? I guess it's depending on the view you're in, right ? like if you're in the view from an artist, it will display all artists songs, and if you're in the view of a specific album, it will display all the songs of the albums ?

Comment: IS_MUSIC is a column Im using to check if the returned row is music and not ringtone or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You could make

```
Album extends SongCollection
```

and

```
Artist extends SongCollection
```

In `SongCollection` you will have

```
abstract List<Song> getSongs();
```

and in `Artist` and `Album` you will override `getSongs()` returning a proper query results.

For the query you may want to have a singleton class `MusicDatabase` with the method `List<Song> query(String queryText, String... params)`

Comment: Should have showed the structure of the class where the method getSongs is. The class is "music", then with some and other methods and getSongs as another method.

Comment: What is "SongCollection"? the parent class to getSongs?

Comment: SongCollection is an abstract class with the abstract method getSongs()
Then Artist overrides getSong to somethng like  MusicDatabase.query('artist=' + artistName()); and Album to smth different

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the many alternative designs that exist for your code , and focussing on your question title alone , you could do something like this :
( This is off my head , untested code written directly into a browser, so may need tweaks to compile )

```
    public <T extends BaseSongs> ArrayList<T> getSongs(Context context, int max, Class<T> cls){
           String select;

            switch (cls. getName()) {
                case "Albums": {
                    select = IS_MUSIC + " != 0 AND ALBUM NOT NULL) GROUP BY (ALBUM";
                    break;
                }
                case "Artists": {
                     select = IS_MUSIC + " != 0 AND ARTIST NOT NULL) GROUP BY (ARTIST";
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                     select = IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
                    break;
                }
            }

       ArrayList<BaseSongs> songList = new ArrayList<>();  // java 7

      if (songCounter < max) {
          /////// Use Reflection
          Constructor ctr = cls.getConstructor(<list the types for ctr args here>);
          songList.add(ctr.newInstance(id, album, artist, title, getArt(context, albumId)));
       }

       return songList;
```

The way you call your getSongs() would be :

`songList = music.getSongs(mView.getContext(), 200, Albums.class);`

Comment: Ok, so what is BaseSongs?

Comment: Base class for Albums , Artists or whatever you want to return a `songList` of

Comment: I was thinking, would it be possible to contract the "album" class that I put on the question to be a method of class "music" (the parent class to "getSongs") so that getSongs calls a local method instead of the external class?

Comment: Mixing `Albums` into `Music` would be a bad design if you ask me. The separation is clean and conceptually correct.